# Magento 2.3.5 and elasticsearch 7.7 error - Undefined factory elasticsearch7

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Magento 2.3.5, elasticsearch 7.7 on Ubuntu 18

Setting up, testing connection went fine, reindexing also...

I get this error:

`Undefined factory elasticsearch7`

in debug log
when trying to use **autocomplete search**.

Site search is working fine.

Anyone any ideas? Or same problem? Solved?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately not.
I tried with a clean catalog and not with migrated data and it worked.
Try to use the module smile/elasticsuite...